# How do I call js function once everytime something happens

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I need to be called every time when my screen width is 1240px. What I mean is, for example, if I resize from 1300px or more to 1200px or less and as soon as it passes through 1240px my function should be called once. Same goes to, for example, if I resize from 1200px or less to 1300px or more and as soon as it passes through 1240px my function is being called once again.

that's what I tried:

```
function toggle() {
    toggle_time = setTimeout('toggle()', 1);
    if (document.body.offsetWidth<=1240) {
        myFunction();
    }
    if (document.body.offsetWidth>=1240) {
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

But it will call my function always and every millisecond what is wrong. Any answer is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks gonna check that out

Answer (score 1):

```
 function listenforwidth(width,callback){
  var store_width=0;
  window.onresize=function(){
   if((window.innerWidth>store_width && window.innerWidth>width )|| (window.innerWidth<store_width && window.innerWidth<width )){
        callback();
   }
   store_width=window.innerWidth;
   }
```

Use like this:

```
 listenforwidth(1024,function test(){
    window.test=null;
   alert("1024 passed");
 });
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for. I need to call a function once, as screen width passes through certain width

Comment: @MartynasJakas No problem. See edit

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use window.onresize event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/onresize

So, something like:

```
function toggle() {
    if (document.body.offsetWidth<=1240) {
        myFunction();
    }
    if (document.body.offsetWidth>=1240) {
        myFunction();
    }
}

window.onresize = toggle;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14891568)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.